# How to remove data frames the names of which are stored in other string variables in R

Tags: r

```
state1 <- "CA"
state2 <- "IL"
state3 <- "FL"
```

CA, IL, and FL are three data frames.
How to write a loop to remove these data frames using paste("state", i) where i is an integer? Assume there are many such data frames so that removing them one by one would be inefficient.

Comment: Why would you keep so many separate data frames instead of keeping them as a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have names of the dataframes in character vector say `states` then you can use 
`rm(list=states)`

Now there are various ways of getting `states`

Just create it and update it when a new state variable is created. 
e.g.

```
CA <- data.frame()
states <- "CA"

IL <- data.frame()
states <- c(states, "IL")

FL <- data.frame()
states <- c(states, "FL")
```

Or

If you have names of object in variables like `state1`, `state2` etc.. then you can do what David suggested

```
states = sapply(paste("state", 1:2, sep=""), get)
rm(list = states)
```

Comment: and how difficult is to get a character vector `c('states1', 'states2')` :-/

Comment: @geektrader: No, those are *not* the variables the OP is trying to delete, so that's not the vector he needs.

Comment: @geektrader: Well, it's at least as hard as removing all of them once you have that vector. If the OP hasn't heard of `get` then he'd have to type out all 50.

Comment: Perhaps show how to get `states` or even just do `rm(list = c(state1, state2, state3))`. Otherwise your Answer is incomplete.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Well that's why I upvoted Andrie's answer else my answer sould have been same as his.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how, but you should never have to do this:

```
CA <- data.frame()
IL <- data.frame()
FL <- data.frame()
ls()
[1] "CA" "FL" "IL"

rm(list=c("CA", "IL", "FL"))
ls()
character(0)
```

What you should do instead, is to have all those objects in a list, then manipulate the list:

```
states <- list(
  CA = data.frame(),
  IL = data.frame(),
  FL = data.frame()
)

str(states)
List of 3
 $ CA:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ IL:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ FL:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
```

Since your list is a single object, you can remove with a simple `rm()`:

```
rm(states)
ls()
character(0)
```

Comment: essentially same answer as mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* remove them like this:

```
rm(list=sapply(paste("state", 1:50, sep=""), get))
```

*However*, this is a bad way to store your data (see [keep data out of variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)). Much better would be to keep all the data frames as a named list, such that you could access them as:

```
states[["CA"]]
states[["IL"]]
```

and remove them all at once with:

```
rm(states)
```

Comment: the loop can be avoided. see my answer below

Comment: @geektrader: See the OP's question. He actually has `state1`, `state2`, etc as separate string variables.

Comment: `rm(list=sapply(get, paste("state", 1:50, sep="")))` did you test this ? it doesn't work for me...

Comment: @agstudy: Sorry- mixed up the order of the two arguments to `sapply`

Comment: @agstudy: as geektrader noted on your answer, state1 and state2 aren't the data frames themselves but strings containing the names of the data frames (not a good approach to storing data, but still)

Comment: @DavidRobinson oops..really not good approch. in that case the use of `get` is correct here! I will delete my answer!

Comment: +1 your answer too for showing better way of storing the data :)

Comment: If we can make some assumptions about the data, we could also use `rm(list = sapply(ls(pattern = "state"), get))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rm` and `get`, but with `do.call`, more elegant since we manipulate a list of instructions.

I assume that N is the number of states.

```
do.call(rm,lapply(paste("state", 1:N, sep=""), get))
```

Comment: state1 and state2 are not dataframes but strings containing object-to-be-deleted names